# git error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check) after download was done

Tags: git, github

> ```
> remote: Counting objects: 3442754, done.
> remote: Compressing objects: 100% (515633/515633), done.
> remote: Total 3442754 (delta 2898137), reused 3442437 (delta 2897904)
> Receiving objects: 100% (3442754/3442754), 721.13 MiB | 246.00 KiB/s, done.
> error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
> fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
> fatal: index-pack failed
> buddy$
> ```

The downloaded data was no more after this process. I don't know why this happened, but when I look at my downloaded directory there are no sources available.
How can I recover the download data?

Comment: You would start with checking your hardware health; this log suggests me there is memory or bus problem. But, if this couldn't help if a broken hardware is out of yoru control...  try to check out the remote data gradually, finding a commit id for each intermediate step and loading only up to it. Or do it using another Internet connection...

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have that issue consistently and:

- if others have the same message, that can mean an issue on the repo hosting service on the remote side: for instance, GitHub had a DDoS attack yesterday ([GitHub status messages](https://status.github.com/messages)).

> 1:04 UTC:
>   As a result of our ongoing DDoS mitigation, we're experiencing high rates of packet loss from users in the Asia-Pacific region.
>   We're working on reducing this disruption to service and will provide additional information when it becomes available.

- if it is only you, try and see of you can reproduce that with a different computer.
  If it is the case, then it could be an issue with the repo content itself.

Answer (score 2):

I have seen this issue when the machine from which the "repo sync" or "git pull" was done had very low memory. I have seen this multiple times and checking the memory it always had 0GB free memory. This also happened when the user machine's OS was upgraded to Ubuntu 14.04 and had the same issue of memory being insufficient though memory was managed well with a previous OS version.

Running the same command from a more powerful machine worked or trying this from a different OS worked.

This is not an answer but i had seen this issue, so an observation and workaround if the issue is related to memory.

Comment: I'm experiencing this as well. Tried git clone on a more powerful computer and it worked perfectly.

Comment: have same issue, git clone works fine on new/bigger machine and fails on older one.

Comment: in my research into this issue, not for lack of memory on the lesser machine (6GB available at time of error, plus another 4GB of swap) nor disk space (865G available on destination drive).    the cpu is getting peaked pretty hard, tried adjusting git's buffering w/these commands but to no avail. git config --global pack.windowMemory 256m 
git config --global pack.packSizeLimit 256m

git config --global http.postBuffer 1024M
git config --global http.maxRequestBuffer 512M
git config --global core.compression 9

Answer (score 1):

I was experiencing this same issue. For me none of the solutions above helped.

I ended up running a memory test (memtest86), and it turns out that 2 of my 4 memory sticks had memory faults. Removing the faulty sticks allowed me to clone the repo without issue (it was a large repo).

Comment: This worked with my case. Tried memtester and it reported some errors in random value test. After removing the faulty memory stick, git works perfectly with large repos.

Answer (score 0):

Recently I encountered the same problem when cloning a git repository on an NFS share with a large git repository (>500MB).

If I ran the `git clone` on the server (I.E. not over NFS) the errors went away.

Further testing identified that occasionally data was getting corrupted while being copied to the server via NFSv4.

After much debugging it turned out the issue was related to a buggy network driver corrupting TCP packets when segmentation and rx/tx checksumming was offloaded to the network interface card.

After disabling the segmentation and rx/tx checksum offload on the network interface card (following the instructions in the following blog post: [How to solve ssh disconnect packet corrupt problems](https://linux-tips.com/t/how-to-solve-ssh-disconnect-packet-corrupt-problems/258)) the data corruption problems on the NFS share went away, as did my issues with git.