# "unknown compression method" when cloning any git repository from anywhere

Tags: git, compression, clone

I'm on an OS X virtual machine, and since this week I can't clone git repositories anymore (and there was no modification to my knowledge).

I first tried to clone a repo from my Gitlab (on another VM), I also tried updating brew, finally I tried to clone a repo from github, and each time I get this error :

```
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
```

whereas all those repositories can be cloned wihtout problem on my other machines

For instance :

```
> git clone https://github.com/less/less.js.git
Cloning into 'less.js'...
remote: Counting objects: 19725, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (16/16), done.
remote: Total 19725 (delta 8), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 19709
Receiving objects: 100% (19725/19725), 10.07 MiB | 389.00 KiB/s, done.
error: inflate: data stream error (unknown compression method)
fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
fatal: index-pack failed
```

I tried updating my git version (which is 2.9.0 now). I also tried not to compress files when cloning but I don't get how to do this... 
Any clue on what is wrong on my machine ?

Comment: A quick google search seems to indicate that this has been solved in the past with new hardware (!). Perhaps you have a memory error.

Comment: I couldn't find any mention of that. Can you provide a link ?

Comment: https://marc.info/?l=git&m=118132705700250&w=4 https://marc.info/?l=git&m=118142354813469&w=4 https://marc.info/?l=git&m=118206731212258&w=4 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573759/git-error-inflate-data-stream-error-incorrect-data-check-after-download-was

Comment: Thanks. So with that in mind I tried to clone a repo on a machine that backups all my virtual machines and I've got exactly the same problem. It seems it's not related to hardware failure. 
In the last link I also read it could be due to a lack of memory, so I added 2Gb, but it doesn't solve the problem

Comment: Beats me. As you noted, the repository is ok. I tried that command as well, and it worked fine. What you are seeing indicates corruption somewhere along the way. Are all of these machines on the same router? Can you try a different path to the internet?

Comment: I have several virtual machines on the same physcal machine (a mac pro) running ESXi. 3 on Ubuntu and 2 on OSX : Sierra and El Capitan (or Yosemite ? I can't recall, I'll have to check tomorrow at work). The El Capitan VM can't git-clone while all the other can. I can't check the network properties of the mac pro nor the vhosts redirecting on each VM right now, but I'll check those asap.
What do you mean about a different path to the internet ? something else than github ? I'll try that

Comment: Note that the first thing I tried and that didn't work for one VM only was to clone a repo from a Gitlab that runs on one of my VMs

Comment: So you're saying that it works with one version of Mac OS X running in a VM, but not another version running in a VM on the same hardware? Please add that information and the Mac OS X versions on which it does and does not work to the question. Also are you saying that you cannot clone _any_ git repository from _any_ source with that one virtual machine?