# git clone regularly has "inflate: data stream error"

Tags: git, git-clone

We are self-hosting our git, first with Bonobo git server, now with gitea.

On more than one occasion, we got the error when trying to clone our main repo (2.2 GB .git folder):

```
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: pack has bad object at offset: ...
fatal: index-pack failed
```

The error sometimes also occurred when using git-fsck, but this time it doesn't. We always took the time to fix this error, but less than a week later, another error comes up.

What could cause this issue, and how can we fix it? The server that hosts the git runs rock stable otherwise, hosting our DC, multiple other programs and web sites (timecards, calendaring, intranet sites...). Should we search for the issue on the server side or would this be an issue with some git client? We haven't got a standardized git client, some use git for windows, some visual studio, some tortoise git.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573759/git-error-inflate-data-stream-error-incorrect-data-check-after-download-was

Comment: The only thing we can be certain of here is that Git has detected data corruption that would otherwise go silently undetected. *Where* that corruption occurred is impossible to say from this alone—you'll need additional diagnostics.

Comment: @torek I would expect git to tell me about corrupted data during upload if it occurred during upload, so that we could rule out corruption during upload in this case, or to return a remote message if corruption was detected on the server before download already. But obviously, git is not so much into good error handling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this problem occurs, it may be related to a failing disk or memory module on the machine hosting the git server software. In our case, testing with "memtest" revealed that at least one of the ECC RAM modules was faulty enough to flip bits.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I got the same error and it was due to lack of disk space on the machine I was attempting to clone to. Once I cleared some disk space, I was able to clone the repo.