# Trouble cloning a Git Repo onto my PYNQ-Z1 board

Tags: git, neural-network, git-clone

I have been trying to clone a Git repo onto my PYNQ-Z1 board for a while and have been running into consistent errors.

This is the command I run:

```
sudo pip3 install git+https://github.com/maltanar/BNN-PYNQ.git
```

I'll be honest I don't understand how Git works entirely and was just trying to follow a tutorial on how to set up a BNN on the PYNQ-Z1, I don't understand why some things are done.

This is what happens when I run that command:

```
WARNING: pip is being invoked by an old script wrapper. This will fail in a future version of pip.
Please see https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5599 for advice on fixing the underlying issue.
To avoid this problem you can invoke Python with '-m pip' instead of running pip directly.
Collecting git+https://github.com/maltanar/BNN-PYNQ.git
  Cloning https://github.com/maltanar/BNN-PYNQ.git to /tmp/pip-req-build-jbgjss9x
ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 128: git clone -q https://github.com/maltanar/BNN-PYNQ.git /tmp/pip-req-build-jbgjss9x Check the log
s for full command output.
WARNING: You are using pip version 20.2.4; however, version 21.3.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the '/usr/bin/python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I have tried doing as it says and upgrading pip however it made no difference and I have since reset the PYNQ image on the SD card.

That is another thing, I have had trouble with the versions of PYNQ image I am using, the latest does not work for me, it gets stuck on Starting kernel, so I am using an older version v2.6.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:

Using just git clone gave this result:

```
xilinx@pynq:~/jupyter_notebooks$ git clone https://github.com/maltanar/BNN-PYNQ 
Cloning into 'BNN-PYNQ'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 1516, done. 
remote: Total 1516 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1516 
Receiving objects: 100% (1516/1516), 26.69 MiB | 4.10 MiB/s, done. 
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check) 
fatal: serious inflate inconsistency 
fatal: index-pack failed
```

Comment: I recommend running the `git clone` command directly instead of doing it with `pip3`. This way you can remove the `-q` option and get the full error output. Once you fix the problem, then you can use `pip3 install` again.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice So doing that I got this output:
`xilinx@pynq:~/jupyter_notebooks$ git clone https://github.com/maltanar/BNN-PYNQ`
`Cloning into 'BNN-PYNQ'...`
`remote: Enumerating objects: 1516, done.`
`remote: Total 1516 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0), pack-reused 1516`
`Receiving objects: 100% (1516/1516), 26.69 MiB | 4.10 MiB/s, done.`
`error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)`
`fatal: serious inflate inconsistency`
`fatal: index-pack failed`
```

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I googled that error and some suggestions were there may be something wrong with the hardware or my internet connection, but cloning it onto my PC with the same internet connection works fine and I have tried doing it on a second board to no avail.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question so you can format the error message better.

Comment: An answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573759/git-error-inflate-data-stream-error-incorrect-data-check-after-download-was suggests it may be due to low memory. How much memory does this board have?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183245/1440565 this answer also has a possible solution.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice I can't currently edit it but I will do later. The board has 512 MB of DDR3 and 16 MB Flash but runs off a 32GB SD card. I will try that second suggested post now