# git clone with fatal: serious inflate inconsistency

Tags: git

I got the git clone error below.

```
Receiving objects: 100% (1103339/1103339), 29.19 GiB | 71.13 MiB/s, done.
error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check)
fatal: serious inflate inconsistency
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output
```

This git repository is about 30G，its an Aosp git repository

this issue raise persistently,  after i try plently of methods.
Heres the solution that i had try before.

**First**  : modify git config file.

```
core.packedgitlimit=51200m
core.packedgitwindowsize=52100m
core.compression=0
pack.windowmemory=8096m
pack.packsizelimit=8096m
pack.deltacachesize=8096m
ssh.postbuffer=524288000
core.repositoryformatversion=0
core.filemode=true
core.bare=false
core.logallrefupdates=true
http.postbuffer=524288000
```

didnt work for me

**Second**: acrroding to stack overflow other questions，I had try to modify the system property like ulimit file

```
real-time non-blocking time  (microseconds, -R) unlimited
core file size              (blocks, -c) 0
data seg size               (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority                 (-e) 0
file size                   (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                     (-i) 191275
max locked memory           (kbytes, -l) 6130312
max memory size             (kbytes, -m) unlimited
open files                          (-n) 2460000
pipe size                (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues         (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority                  (-r) 0
stack size                  (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time                   (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes                  (-u) 191275
virtual memory              (kbytes, -v) unlimited
file locks                          (-x) unlimited
```

didnt work for me

**Third**: try to create an empty directory with git init

```
git init

git remote add origin xxxurl

git fetch --all --depath 1
```

this solution raised another error like

```
fatal: fetch-pack: invalid index-pack output 95 GiB | 54.24 MiB/s
Could not fetch origin
```

If theres any other solutions？Or maybe i should change the network?

This my device info:

Ubuntu：22.0.4

Git：2.34.1

Cpu: 16 core

Memory：48Gb ram and 50Gb swapFile size

Rom: 8Tb HardDisk

Comment: Does this answer your question? [git error: inflate: data stream error (incorrect data check) after download was done](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22573759/git-error-inflate-data-stream-error-incorrect-data-check-after-download-was)

Comment: Thanks for your reply，Follwing your link, may be i would try to start a memory test via memtest86

Comment: I had try a memory test via memtest86 , report that memory work fine.

Comment: There is also the chance that the source repository simply is corrupted. If you have access to it, can you try locally cloning the repo into another directory to rule out that case? Or, it could even be a memory error on the server side.

Comment: @JoachimSauer, Thanks for reply,I had check it out. Maybe is not the server repository problem.
1. I had try to clone the source code from git-lab, problem still there.
2. I use other machine to clone the source code from git-lab, Its work fine.
3. I also try to clone the source code from Step2 machine in LAN，the problem still there
4. Then I clone another repository or clone from another machine in LAN，the problem still there
Beside that
 i reinstall the System, from Ubuntu 18.0.2 to Ubuntu 22.0.2，Cant fixed it.
then try to clone to SSD than HardDisk, Cant fixed it.

Comment: @JoachimSauer Maybe just some hardware errors on my machine, like NIC error or just other network error, because i had try to zip the git pack file and copy via LAN from another machine, then unzip it and git pull, still this, cant figure it out. Its a little bit odd

Comment: Sounds like faulty hardware indeed, the most common source is actually faulty  memory. Have you run memtest86 (or the equivalent for your architecture) as suggested in the dupe link?

Comment: @JoachimSauer Yes, I had finished run memtest86 , and the memory report seem quite normal. Beside that, I had change another Machine and still plugin the same Ram stick. Its work fine at first, but after i delete the whole repository on harddisk then clone it again, this issue suddenly occured again... Maybe just the memory stick error. I change to a totally new Machine with ddr5 ram stick, The problem solved, and no matter what i delete it work pretty fines.